# displaying a Message using SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am trying to a display message when i will push save button saying that the content got saved using SWT. Can anyone please help me.

**Note:** I am not using **Jface**, `Shell`, `Display`. I am using a `Composite`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you *are* using a `Display` and a base `Shell`. But these are hidden behind your Eclipse RCP app. I'm guessing you are creating your message dialog in the `createContents(Composite)` method of a `ViewPart`, correct?

You can access the `Display` with `Display.getCurrent()` anywhere in your code, and you can get the active `Shell` with `parent.getActiveShell()`.

If you don't want to use `JFace`, use the `MessageBox` widget from SWT.

```
MessageBox box = new MessageBox(parent.getActiveShell(), SWT.CANCEL | SWT.OK);
box.setText("Title");
box.setMessage("This will be the message");

box.open(); // Call this on button pressed. Returns SWT.OK or SWT.CANCEL
```

If you want specific features for the `MessageBox`, you can either ask me in a comment, or [check out these 18 Java code examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox).

Comment: @NikhilaBenjaram Alright, cool. Make sure you accept the answer for someone else to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use as below

```
MessageBox box = new MessageBox(comp.getShell(), SWT.CANCEL | SWT.OK);
```

Where comp is Composite.